# return indexes of filtered dataframe as values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe like the input dataframe below.  I would like to create a new dataframe, where I filter my original data frame to only return the indexes of every column value above 0.66.  I know I could filter the whold dataframe like

```
df[df>0.66]
```

which would give me NaN values for all entries below 0.66, but then how do I get the indexes in to each column?  Any tips are greatly appreciated.

input data:

```
                    str_home_page  str_emails  str_bigticket_orders
str_home_page             1.000000   0.680272             0.654346
str_emails                0.680272   1.000000             0.927515
str_bigticket_orders      0.654346   0.927515             1.000000
```

desired output:

```
                    str_home_page       str_emails          str_bigticket_orders
0                   str_home_page       str_home_page          
1                   str_emails          str_emails              str_emails
2                   str_bigticket_orders                str_bigticket_orders
```

Comment: Should `str_bigticket_orders` be under the `str_emails` column in your output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just using `mul` with Boolean dataframe

```
(df>0.66).mul(df.index.values,0)
```